# Препроцессор в С/С++.

Tags: c, c++

Что означают символы # и ## в директиве #define?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Символ # означает, что последующий аргумент должен быть заключен в кавычки, то есть должен восприниматься как строка:

#define TOSTRING(a) #a
TOSTRING(something) будет заменен на "something"

Символ ## означает "склейку"

#define SETSOMETHING(a) set##a
SETSOMETHING(something) будет заменен на setsomething

Случаи, когда это используется, встречаются не так часто, но всё же бывают (мне доводилось)

Comment: Например, когда C++17 стандарт еще не вышел, а ты уже жаждешь рефлексии )))